# Recall nth word from previous command that used brace expansion

Tags: bash

I frequently find myself copying an existing file before editing it. I'm quite lazy, so of course I make use of brace expansion:

```
$ cp some/long/path/to/file{a,b}.txt
$ vi some/long/path/to/fileb.txt
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to save even more tedious typing by referring to the expanded "fileb" path somehow.

Bash's event/word designators don't seem to help (`vi !!:2` for example) as they refer to the command before expansion of the {a,b}. Is there a way to refer to the post-expansion command history?

Comment: Not a general-purpose answer, but `$_` will give you the last argument after expansion, which would work for your example.

Comment: Yep, it does solve the specific case that made me ask the general question, thanks for that!